# merge multiple excel files in one dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a lots of excel files +200, all of these have the same format.

the directorys are saved in this list

```
dir_list = ['all','files]
```

I want to convert all of them into one single df

below is what I want to select from each excel file into the new df

```
used_col = ['Dimension', 'Length','Customer']


df_x = pd.read_excel(file,sheet_name='Tabelle1',skiprows=3,skipinitialspace=True, usecols=used_col)
```

how can I do that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import multiple csv files into pandas and concatenate into one DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906474/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, you need to use `concat` to create a single df from all files.

```py
tmp = [] 
used_col = ['Dimension', 'Length','Customer']
for file in dir_list:
      df_x = pd.read_excel(file,sheet_name='Tabelle1',skiprows=3,skipinitialspace=True, usecols=used_col)
       tmp.append(df_x)
final_df = pd.concat(tmp)
```